# Want SQL Query to display Data from Row into Column

Tags: mysql

Is there is any SQL statement to generate this report?

```
Original Data In table (Quotation Analysis Detail)
-----------------------

Doc_No  Doc_Date    Item_ID     Qty   Rate  BAsic_Amount  Net_Amount  Supplier_ID
1       2011/06/23  520720E    10     123    1230          1230           1
1       2011/06/23  520720E    10     345    3450          3450           18
```

I need to display data in Crystal Report as below format (Cross Tab Not working).  Need SQL statement

```
              |  Supplier ID's |
-------------------------------------------------
              1       |       18      and so on
------------------------------------------------
QTY          10       |      10
Rate         123      |      345
Basic_Amount 1230     |      3450
Net_Amount   1230     |       3450
```

.
.
.
and so on.

Comment: Do you mean pivoting the table? The records spreading horizontally. Do you consider import to excel, then pivot it?

Comment: I don't want to export it to excel,rather I need it in crystal report. I need SQL statement for this type of display

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying to do is to UNPIVOT a table... You already have in a normalized mode, but want them columnar per each supplier for like a side-by-side comparison and each column... you would also have to have a "definitive" number of suppliers you wanted to compare which would get into a VERY ugly / long SQL command...  It COULD be done, but QUITE ugly...

Is this your intent??? and if so, would you be supplying a specific list of suppliers you wanted in a side-by-side comparison?